# Why does RealmRecyclerViewAdapter not work?

Tags: android, realm

I am running into an odd problem with `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter`. I override the class, specifying `null` for the initial data and `true` for the `autoUpdate`. The adapter is already registered for the RecyclerView. Then later in `onResume()` I perform the following:

`theAdapter.updateData(myQuery.findAllAsync());`

However, when my Activity is shown, the RecyclerView is empty, despite the fact I know there are results. When I fire up the debugger and step into the listener created internally in the `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter`, I can see what is happening. There are no ranges for added, removed, or deleted in the `changeSet` argument, but the `changeSet` argument is also not `null`. This means it never calls `notifyDataSetChanged()`. I can see my 300+ results in the `collection` argument.

I have pasted the code below. The conditional that I presume is supposed to be true, but is not, is `if (changeSet == null)`. Any idea what is going on here? Did they change Realm to never return a null change set, but forget to update the adapter?

I am running Realm 5.4.1 and the adapter is 2.0.0.

Edit: as an experiment, I added a `Thread.sleep(1000)` on the main thread after calling `updateData()`. This actually causes the RecyclerView to populate with the results, because the query has time to finish async before the adapter starts trying to bind values to view holders. This is not really a surprise but I figured I'd share it.

```
    // This is from the RealmRecyclerViewAdapter class
    private OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener createListener() {
    return new OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(Object collection, OrderedCollectionChangeSet changeSet) {
            // null Changes means the async query returns the first time.
            if (changeSet == null) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                return;
            }
            // For deletions, the adapter has to be notified in reverse order.
            OrderedCollectionChangeSet.Range[] deletions = changeSet.getDeletionRanges();
            for (int i = deletions.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                OrderedCollectionChangeSet.Range range = deletions[i];
                notifyItemRangeRemoved(range.startIndex, range.length);
            }

            OrderedCollectionChangeSet.Range[] insertions = changeSet.getInsertionRanges();
            for (OrderedCollectionChangeSet.Range range : insertions) {
                notifyItemRangeInserted(range.startIndex, range.length);
            }

            OrderedCollectionChangeSet.Range[] modifications = changeSet.getChangeRanges();
            for (OrderedCollectionChangeSet.Range range : modifications) {
                notifyItemRangeChanged(range.startIndex, range.length);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Realm 5.4.1 and the adapter is ***2.0.0***.

This is why.

You must update `realm-android-adapters` to `3.0.0` or newer.

---

> ***Realm-Java 5.0.0 (2018-03-15)***
>
> **Breaking Changes**
>
> The OrderedCollectionChangeSet parameter in OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener.onChange() is no longer nullable. Use changeSet.getState() instead (#5619).

---

> ***Realm-Android-Adapters 3.0.0 (2018-04-06)***
>
> **Breaking Changes**
>
> Only works with Realm Java 5.0.0+. ([#137](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters/pull/137))

Where the PR says:

> Add support for non-null changesets

And has the following changes:

```
            if (changeSet == null) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                return;
            }

///////////////////////////////////////////

            if (changeSet.getState() == OrderedCollectionChangeSet.State.INITIAL) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                return;
            }
```

So in Realm 5.0.0+, the changeSet is never null, so `notifyDataSetChanged()` is not triggered.

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks!